# Redirect stdout to a file with bash command in brackets

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I have a bash command built from an array as following:

```
cmd=(java -Xmx8g -jar program.jar input.vcf ">" output.vcf)
```

I do not have problems when using `echo`:

```
echo "${cmd[@]}"
java -Xmx8g -jar program.jar input.vcf > output.vcf
```

But when I run it using:

```
"${cmd[@]}"
```

The  `>`  is ignored and I cannot redirect stdout to `output.vcf` file.

Please, could you suggest me a solution?

Comment: When you pass it that way, the `>` isn't *ignored*; instead, it's passed to the Java program as an argument.

Comment: That's a (security and correctness) feature, not a bug -- it means that data (like arguments) can't be treated as code without intentional action to the contrary.

Comment: You could use `eval "${cmd[@]}"`.

Comment: @ooga, ...thereby completely bypassing said security, and also losing any advantage from using proper array expansion syntax.

Comment: BTW, the answer provided by @JohnKugelman is echoed as a best practice by BashFAQ #50: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be better to store the command in a function. Functions are for commands, variables are for data.

```
cmd() {
    java -Xmx8g -jar program.jar input.vcf > output.vcf
}

cmd
```

(I implore you *not* to use `eval`, which allow your variable-based approach to work, but opens up a whole other can of worms.)

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer [John Kugelman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25943830/1392132) but if you *really mean* to execute the words stored in the array, you could `eval` them:

```
cmd=(date '>' date.stdout)
eval "${cmd[@]}"
```

Be warned that this might open up all kinds of security holes.